# how to get data from AAVE with Protocol Data Provider contract

Tags: solidity

i want make test and get data about DAI asset with solidity . i used this interfaces.

```
 interface IProtocolDataProvider {
  struct TokenData {
    string symbol;
    address tokenAddress;
  }
   
  function getAllReservesTokens() external view returns (TokenData[] memory);

  function getAllATokens() external view returns (TokenData[] memory);

  function getReserveConfigurationData(address asset) external view returns (uint256 decimals, uint256 ltv, uint256 liquidationThreshold, uint256 liquidationBonus, uint256 reserveFactor, bool usageAsCollateralEnabled, bool borrowingEnabled, bool stableBorrowRateEnabled, bool isActive, bool isFrozen);

  function getReserveData(address asset) external view returns (uint256 availableLiquidity, uint256 totalStableDebt, uint256 totalVariableDebt, uint256 liquidityRate, uint256 variableBorrowRate, uint256 stableBorrowRate, uint256 averageStableBorrowRate, uint256 liquidityIndex, uint256 variableBorrowIndex, uint40 lastUpdateTimestamp);

  function getUserReserveData(address asset, address user) external view returns (uint256 currentATokenBalance, uint256 currentStableDebt, uint256 currentVariableDebt, uint256 principalStableDebt, uint256 scaledVariableDebt, uint256 stableBorrowRate, uint256 liquidityRate, uint40 stableRateLastUpdated, bool usageAsCollateralEnabled);

  function getReserveTokensAddresses(address asset) external view returns (address aTokenAddress, address stableDebtTokenAddress, address variableDebtTokenAddress);
}
```

and my contract is :

```
contract getData{

    IProtocolDataProvider public AD;

    constructor(address _ada) {
        AD = IProtocolDataProvider(_ada);
    }

    function getD(address _asset) public view returns(uint){

        (
            uint256 availableLiquidity, uint256 totalStableDebt, uint256 totalVariableDebt, uint256 liquidityRate, uint256 variableBorrowRate, uint256 stableBorrowRate, uint256 averageStableBorrowRate, uint256 liquidityIndex, uint256 variableBorrowIndex, uint40 lastUpdateTimestamp
        ) = AD.getReserveData(_asset);
        return availableLiquidity;
    }
}
```

i used both (MAIN AND KOVAN) address of Protocol Data Provider from AAVE source :
https://docs.aave.com/developers/deployed-contracts/deployed-contracts

and i test it with DAI address : 0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F , and in remix i get this error : call to getData.getD errored: VM execution error.
Reverted 0x .

any help please